# Django REST framework is slow

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm started using the Django REST framework in preparation for production, but unfortunately, it is performing quite slowly.

I am calling an array of 500 dictionaries, each with 5 key-value pairs each. In the shell, the call-time is not noticeable at all - you press enter, and it's done. Previously, when I was serving the same content directly without the REST framework, there was also no noticeable delay. However, with the REST framework, it takes about 1 - 2 seconds after the page has rendered for the content to display.

I do not think this is due to javascript as hitting the same details through the browseable API results in a similar delay.

Also, I am **NOT** cacheing at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the view to see what is taking up the time? I've used [this decorator](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango) to profile views before.

Comment: Did you try to roll back to your previous solution and do the same API call? It might have nothing to do with the library.

Comment: @Torsten - Just confirmed that the direct call to postgresql is much faster. I'll confirm if it's the JS, but again, since hitting the built-in browseable API is equally slow, I feel it may be DRF.

Comment: Have you tried running simplejson.dumps on the response (in the shell) to see how fast it actually serializes into json? If it's still slow, you might need to use the [simplejson C extension](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), if not, please test DRF's response when called from a direct http request (for instance, using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) or [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way anyone else is going to be able to debug this for you from the details given in the question.

- Are you reusing an existing generic view or writing your own view?
- Are you serializing the data, if so what does your serializer definition look like?
- Does the issue manifest when rendering to JSON, or just when rendering to the Browsable API?
- You mention serving the content without REST framework - what did the views looks like before, and what do they look like after?

The REST framework views are *trivial*, so use a profiling tool, or simply override them and add some timing.  Likewise the renderers are *trivial* - subclass whatever renderer you're using at the moment, override `.render()` and add a couple of timing calls either side of calling the parent's `.render()` method.

If you think you've narrowed down a problem to a specific area then throw together a minimal test case and submit it as an issue.

The serialization itself is unlikely to be an issue, I've used the same serialization engine to replicate Django's fixture dumping and there was no significant degradation.

It's feasible that if you're doing lookups across model relationships you might need to add `.select_related()` or `.prefetch_related()` calls when constructing the queryset, exactly as you would with any other Django view.

---

**Edit**: Note that following on from this post there were significant serializer speed improvements made, [as noted in this ticket](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/433).

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try and submit an issue on GH if there's still a problem.

Comment: The generic views I used were the same before and after. I added a prefetch_related() to the query set and am getting the same delay with DRF. Will profile and update.

Comment: Just another update: I've tested the same setup with tastypie and it is loading quite quickly. However, I will still try to debug this as I'm hoping to use DRF in the future anyway.

Comment: If you could post some example code that demonstrates the issue you're seeing I'll try to look into it.